# Item assignment algorithm on python

Tags: python

I have a set of user preferences on different items. For example, let's say there are three items, and the user preferences are:

```
User 1: Item A > Item B > Item C
User 2: Item B > Item A > Item C
User 3: Item A > Item C > Item B
```

The real scenario has 25 users and 25 items, but the idea is the same. My goal here is to offer a best fitting solution, i.e. the one that offers a highest-ranking match for each user overall but not necessarily the maximum number of #1 preferences. Importantly, each item can only be assigned once.

What algorithm could I use on Python to solve this? Thanks!

I tried using Networkx simplex, but I got this error: networkx.exception.NetworkXUnfeasible: total node demand is not zero

```
`Sample preference:
`User1 = ('User1', [20,24,17,22,7,6,5,11,25,8,1,9,23,12,2,19,21,15,16,14,13,4,18,10,3])`

`# (name, index, limit)
no_items=25
C=[]
for i in range(1,no_items+1):
    C.append(('s'+str(i),i,1))

""" Helper """
def get_cost(ranking, index):
    return ranking.index(index)**2                        # quadratic penalty

""" Min-cost flow graph """
G = nx.DiGraph()

# Demands
for p in P:
    G.add_node(p[0], demand=-1)
    G.add_node('sink', demand=len(P))

# layer 1
for p, c in itertools.product(P, C):
    G.add_edge(p[0], c[0], weight=get_cost(p[1], c[1]))

# layer 2
for c in C:
    G.add_edge(c[0], 'sink', capacity=c[2])

flowCost, flowDict = nx.network_simplex(G)
#flowCost, flowDict = nx.capacity_scaling(G)
print('Cost: ', flowCost)

""" SOLUTION """
for p in P:
    for c in C:
        if flowDict[p[0]][c[0]]:
            print(p[0], '->', c[0])`
```

Comment: Please, add the import lines to your code, and mention, or tag, the external libraries you are using.

Comment: This feels hard to understand...```My goal here is to offer a best fitting solution, i.e. the one that offers a highest-ranking match for each user overall but not necessarily the maximum number of #1 preferences. Importantly, each item can only be assigned once.```. What are your values for these `items`? The way you wrote your code looks off and it is hard to understand, you would perhaps get a better answer if you defined the output you want between users `1`-`3` and their defined items

Comment: "best fitting solution" [Arrow's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow%27s_impossibility_theorem) has entered the chat.

Comment: It is not the Arrow's problem, but it's still very likely to be NP-hard. On 25 users/items you might have a chance, but you need to be a lot more explicit on the metric you're trying to optimize

Comment: [Ranked voting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranked_voting) does sound like a fitting solution.